# Backspace suddenly logs me out

Tags: keyboard, zorin

I have Zorin on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220. Yesterday upon turning it on the backspace key will now send me to the lock screen. Xmodmap shows that keybinding 22 is backspace, and in Zorin's key shortcuts under the devices menu logout and lock are both tied to something else. I have tried a couple different methods of remapping the key- and backspace still locks the screen. Does anyone know what could have suddenly changed to do this? Only thing I have done differently with it lately is use an external docking station that receives keyboard and mouse input from a USB switch with my desktop. It does not do this while docked only when I undock it.

Comment: Log you out. Or lock your session. Please edit question to be clear.

Comment: `xev` might help shed some light on the problem - it show X events - so what the X server is recieving - which might show what is wrong with your backspace key.

Comment: I am sorry it locks the session. I believe this is the corresponding xev message from when I press backspace:                                                                         
   KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  122 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Answer (score 1):

ctrl-alt-backspace is sometimes configured to kill the windowing system. So if ctrl and alt key is pressed, it would take you to the login screen. But not the lock screen.